# How to implement a screen in react native app without adding it to drawer navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using react navigation v5, and i have a drawer navigator with a few screens, but now i ran into a problem. I have a profile screen that i dont want to display on the drawer navigator, so im thinking i have to use a stack navigator with this profile screen. But I dont know how to connect these two navigators, with the ability to navigate between them. How do i do this? My code is:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator();

export const MyStackNavigator = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator>
      {user && <StackNavigator.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />}
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

export const AppNavigator = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <DrawerNavigator.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => {
        return (
          <SafeAreaView
            style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 50 : 20 }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              {!user ? (
                <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("../assets/logo.png")}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }}
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      textAlign: "center",
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: "red",
                    }}
                  >
                    Couples.dk
                  </Text>
                </View>
              ) : (
                <View style={{ marginBottom: 20, alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: config.SERVER_URL + user.profileImagePath }}
                    style={{
                      width: 75,
                      height: 75,
                      borderRadius: 50,
                      marginBottom: 10,
                    }}
                  />
                  <Button title="Se Profil" color="#F44336" />
                </View>
              )}
            </View>
            <DrawerItemList {...props} />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
              <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Logout" color="#F44336" />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        );
      }}
    >
      {!user && <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />}
      {user && (
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="Søg Brugere" component={BrowseUsers} />
      )}
      {user && <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="Match" component={Match} />}
      {user && <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} />}
      {user && (
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen name="Favoritter" component={Favorites} />
      )}
    </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};
```

and in app.js

```
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        socket,
        setSocket,
        onlineUsers,
        setOnlineUsers,
        pushToken,
        setPushToken,
        activeConversation,
        setActiveConversation,
      }}
    >
      {initiated && (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <AppNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding options to the screen in drawer navigator:

```
   {user && (
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            drawerLabel: () => null,
            title: null,
            drawerIcon: () => null,
          }}
        />
      )}
```